# CSS3 Zoom animation with border-radius

Tags: css

I need a way to make a zoom animation with CSS3 in a div with `border-radius`. But as you can see below, it doesn't work well:

[image]

Working Code: https://jsfiddle.net/n5owxmch/

**CSS:**

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 540px;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;

  -moz-transition: all 21s;
  -webkit-transition: all 21s;
  transition: all 21s;
}
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s600x600/e35/17661731_634657496725091_8999479055321399296_n.jpg" alt="pepsi" width="540" height="548">

  <div class="item-overlay top"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: In what way does it not work well?

Comment: Your example works great for me, what exactly isn’t working well?

Comment: @LGSon During the animation, the border is not round as you can see in the screenshot above and on jsFiddle.

Comment: @LarsBeck During the animation, the border is not round as you can see in the screenshot above and on jsFiddle.

Comment: This is happening just in Chrome. Edge and Firefox works fine.

Comment: Well, for me it is round, in Chrome!! ... And btw, when using `transform`, you need to set the `img` to `display: block;`

Comment: @adricadar is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: @LGSon I am using chrome, thanks. Could you try with chrome too :) ?

Comment: I just did... works fine

Comment: @xRobot I see rounded borders in Chrome on macOS, Ubuntu, and Windows

Comment: do you need something like this? http://codepen.io/JohnRiordan/pen/sIyuL

Comment: works fine in ff,chrome,ie10,edge. i get this problem with opera.

Comment: **Do note**, when using `transform`, you need to set the `img` to `display: block;`

Comment: @LGSon Added display:block and z-index: https://jsfiddle.net/n5owxmch/3/ but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Does this one work? https://jsfiddle.net/n5owxmch/4/

Comment: @LGSon No, still the same problem

Comment: What browser and version and on which OS?

Comment: @LGSon Windows 10 and latest Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my research I reproduced this just in Chrome (*Edge and Firefox works fine*). To solve it I added `z-index` and vendor prefixes for `border-radius` see below .

Prioritize the `.item` by adding `z-index: 100;` and deprioritize the image with `z-index: 0;`. Basically this will enforce the image to be under the `.item`.

And I added vendor-prefixes (`-moz-` and `-webkit-`) for `border-radius`:

```
  -moz-border-radius:10px; /* add this */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* add this */
```

See snippet:

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  z-index: 100; /* add this */
  position: relative;
  
  -moz-border-radius:10px; /* add this */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* add this */
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 540px;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 0; /* add this */
  -moz-transition: all 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s600x600/e35/17661731_634657496725091_8999479055321399296_n.jpg" alt="pepsi" width="540" height="548">

  <div class="item-overlay top"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since `z-index` only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed) there must be something else what is wrong

Comment: @LGSon In my version of Chrome: `Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)` sometimes didn't work.

Comment: @adricadar What do you mean with _sometimes didn't work_?

Comment: @xRobot Try adding this `-moz-border-radius:10px; /* add this */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* add this */`, as well. O run my example again, I already added them.

Comment: @LGSon I mean, if I hover multiple times, sometimes I can see the corners. I saw your example, and is the same in my `Chrome` version.